# How come Maurice didn't use his horse Philippe to go back to Villeneuve?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

When Belle takes her father's place in the Beast's "prison cell", Maurice is dragged out by the Beast. The next time we see him is in the tavern at the village, and he doesn't have his horse : when he tries to lead Gaston to save Belle, he sits in Gaston's horse-drawn car.

Meanwhile, after the "Be Our Guest" number, Belle goes to the West Wing but the Beast finds her and scares her away. Then Belle leaves riding Philippe : the horse was still there.

So why didn't Maurice use his horse to go back to the village faster in order to find help? Did he expect Belle to escape so soon he decided to leave his horse for her? Did the Beast drag Maurice away up to the castle grounds' doors?